# How to fix this python syntax error for the code segment given below

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICnIu.png)

`

```
# Define output GEE Asset names
change_primary_asset_name = f'users/{"Annanya"}/{"vegetation-change"}/vegetation_change_primary'
change_secondary_asset_name = f'users/{"Annanya"}/{"vegetation-change"}/vegetation_change_secondary'

# Check if GEE Asset already exists prior to export; primary change
if(change_primary_asset:= ee.FeatureCollection(change_primary_asset_name)):
```

Comment: In future it would be helpful for errors to be copy and pasted rather than sending screenshots.  It enables users to see the issue straight away and them be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error does give the reason.

```
if(change_primary_asset:= ee.FeatureCollection(change_primary_asset_name))
```

Is not valid syntax.  If you are checking if two variables are equal you need to use `==` so in your example:

```
if(change_primary_asset == ee.FeatureCollection(change_primary_asset_name)):
```

I suspect this is a simple typo but if not then I'd suggest checking out the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) on flow control statements.